# Has any work been done to integrate Zoom and CiviCRM

Tags: zoom

Outcome would be something along the lines that an attendee of Zoom meeting (eg Zoom id 234) gets added as a participant to Event X (which would have a custom field with 234 in it to help link to Zoom data)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like [NCN Civi Zoom](https://github.com/krd-consulting/ncn-civi-zoom) may already provide integration between Civi and Zoom webinars - thanks to Raphael for sharing so we or others can hopefully build more features in to it.

Comment: very timely - zoom has become a household name.

Answer (score 1):

Repo has moved to https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/ncn-civi-zoom thanks to Veda Consulting

Answer (score 1):

There is also [CiviZoom](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civizoom) by LCD.