# How can I enable self-serve sign in / check in to an Event?

Tags: civievent

I'm using Civi 5.31 on Drupal 7.

I want to enable self-serve check-in / sign in for an Event. Attendees should be able to click a link (and/or scan a QR code) to either RSVP for the Event, and receive a Status of Attended, or, update a previous RSVP with a Status of Registered to Attended.

Only attendees physically present at the meeting, or participating via Zoom, Jitsi etc will be given the link/shown the QR code to scan.

There is an *existing* self-service capability for participants to Cancel or Transfer a registration, and to set time limits for a 'window' within which to cancel or transfer. Self-serve check in / sign in could work similarly.

[image: cancel_transfer_event_reg_cicicrm]

I know there are various ways for 'staff' or a meeting organizer to do this for all attendees, but I want to avoid the manual tedium of updating multiple attendees from Registered to Attended by allowing self-serve check-in/sign-ins.

Thanks!

Comment: civi - zoom integration exists but not clear that answers your requirement. not sure why you are not just sending them a link to the event registration page.

Comment: and it wouldn't be me if i didn't make a Webform/Caldera suggestion, but you should be able to fire a checksum link for an existing participant to either type of form such that they can then just click 'Confirm' to alter their participant status for example

Comment: Pete thanks will check out the checksum link idea using a webform (we're running Drupal). As to why :) - "I want to avoid the manual tedium of updating multiple attendees from Registered to Attended by allowing self-serve check-in/sign-ins."

Comment: And yes, they are being sent a link to the registration page, most of them have registered in advance, some register as walk-ins during the meeting.

Comment: Definitely interested in the CiviCRM/Zoom integration(s), I'll check here on Stack Exchange and in the extensions directory. Any pointers to repos etc you're thinking of?

Comment: Just found this, checking out the linked repo - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/35094/186

Comment: Seeing this as a possible solution - "It updates the participant status accordingly as Attended" - here -

Comment: https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/ncn-civi-zoom

Answer (score 2):

I had the same process in place before started using civi - zoom integration.
The process looked like this:

1. Create webform to update participant (an existing contact) with checksum.
2. Use [google qr to generate the QR code](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes) with token so that by scanning the qr code takes you to [https://your.org/node/2?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}](https://your.org/node/2?cid1=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D)
3. They can click submit to mark themselves as attended (or you can even make this form auto submit with simple javascript).
4. You can set that thank you page after submission is actually a redirect to the online conference link or wherever.

It's a bit hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of newish extensions that aim to help with the process described by you. First of all you may want to have a look at the [Event-Checkin Extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/eventcheckin/en/latest/) which allows to generate QR-Checkin-Codes.

The [Event Invitation extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/eventinvitation/en/latest/) allows you to invite contacts via a unique link / QR-Code incl. a RSVP-Form.

Finally the extension [Custom Event Communication](https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/) allows you to automate/support sending out event emails with the relevant links, QR codes and other information.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, will check out those extensions.